# Orchard Direct Links on Azure

Tags: orchardcms

Orchard1.3 installed on Azure.  Have built from source

How do I get a nice download link (which doesn't work, but from googling I think should work on single hosted machine) like:

http://www.davemateer.com/media/Default/CodeCamp2012/CodeCampPresentation.zip

instead of this one (which does work)

https://mateerstorage3.blob.core.windows.net/media/Default/CodeCamp2012/CodeCampPresentation.zip

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Oh, we are going to have the same problem i think, as we might go and host on azure with downloadable pdf files in the resource directory. I do have a intrest in an answer, but can't provide one myself at this moment

Comment: Orchard1.4 is out today, and there is a Webinar on Tue6th at 16:00UTC.  I'll keep my eyes open, and write back with an answer if and when :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a module that exposes its own routes, and proxy the contents through there. It's going to have horrendous performance but it will work.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand - its a nice to have only.  Congrats on 1.4release yesterday.  I'm considering looking at not Azure hosting as scale-ability isn't a big deal for me currently.